# questions to tag volumes by salt, either state or module?

Tags: saltstack, salt-cloud

How salt can tag ec2 ebs volumes? I have tried all different ways I could think of, but non of them working:

First, tag volumes in profile:

```
   block_device_mappings:
     - DeviceName: /dev/sdb
       Ebs.VolumeSize: 10
       Ebs.VolumeType: standard
       tags: { 'env': 'test' }
```

Secondly, tag volumes in salt state:

```
/dev/sdb:
  boto_ec2.volumes_tagged:
    - tag_maps:
      - filters:
        volume_ids: [ vol-0efe9141c40301871 ]
        #'attachment.device': /dev/xvdb
      - tags:
        env: test
```

I got the error when the state was run:

```
Comment: An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/var/tmp/.root_5c1176_salt/py2/salt/state.py", line 1745, in call
              **cdata['kwargs'])
            File "/var/tmp/.root_5c1176_salt/py2/salt/loader.py", line 1702, in wrapper
              return f(*args, **kwargs)
            File "/var/tmp/.root_5c1176_salt/py2/salt/states/boto_ec2.py", line 1209, in volumes_tagged
              r = __salt__['boto_ec2.set_volumes_tags'](**args)
            File "/var/tmp/.root_5c1176_salt/py2/salt/modules/boto_ec2.py", line 1647, in set_volumes_tags
              raise SaltInvocationError('Tag filters must be a dictionary: got {0}'.format(filters))
          SaltInvocationError: Tag filters must be a dictionary: got None`
```

Finally, have looked the module `boto_ec2.set_volumes_tags`, but I just could not find out the syntax and how to put the filters and tags.

Please anyone could show me how to tag volumes by salt.
Thanks,
Roger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Just post the solution here in case anyone have the similar question:

It is using `boto_ec2.volumes_tagged` state pretty similar with my original state. However, the format is a bit unusual than normal salt states:

```
/dev/sdb:
   boto_ec2.volumes_tagged:
   # ec2_profile is defined in pillar
   - profile: ec2_profile
   - tag_maps:
     - filters:
         attachment.device: /dev/sdb
       tags:
         env: 'test'
```